# How to automatically resize all widgets when Display DPI scale is changed?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5

On Windows, in the display settings I could change the size of the contents of the screen in %.
Now, if the display settings were updated BEFORE launching the GUI, the GUI would look fine.
However, if the display settings were updated WHILE the GUI is open, then all fonts would increase (as expected) in size but the widgets such as push buttons and others would stay the same size (unlike in the previous scenario).

So after some research and thinking, it might make sense to use:

1. [QScreen::logicalDotsPerInchChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#logicalDotsPerInchChanged) signal to signal that display settings were changed.
2. Upon receiving this signal, the whole ui window should update all of its widgets to match this new scale % factor.
   Btw, this question was asked and solved before in the Qt Forum; however, without showing some implementation as in : [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/69978/scaling-widget-according-to-screen-scaling-ratio-in-os)

So my question resides in how can this be implemented:

For number 1: where do I place this signal connection and how can I react to it
For number 2: what is a good way to resize or update widgets without doing so one by one, but rather at the ui window level.

Comment: First of all, are you using a layout manager? Then, there is a lot of difference on when a window is going to be mapped (shown the first time) and what happens after that. Most importantly, once a window is already shown, it usually try to keep its size even if its contents change, and will only update it when necessary: consider that when a window is shown the first time, it has a size that is normally bigger than its minimum possible size, and when the DPI change it will eventually force its resizing only if the new computed minimum size is not enough; this means that if the new DPI ->

Comment: -> do not require a new minimum size that is bigger than the current, the window will probably not be resized at all. This, obviously, is assuming that layout manager are correctly used; if they are not, then the problem is exactly that: you *must* use layouts.

Comment: @musicamante Yes, all the widgets fall under some layouts.. Do you mean that having layouts and playing around with the size policies would be enough, or might I be missing something? Bcz if this is the case then I do not want the window to retain its size if not necessary as the dpi changes -> is there a way to circumvent that?

Comment: Well, I cannot test as I have no means to do that, but I'd say that you could try to connect the signal with a call to [`adjustSize()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#adjustSize) on the top level window. Unless specific and complex size hints or policies are used, it could be enough to ensure that the window gets resized as much as it would appear when started with the new DPI already set.

Comment: @musicamante I just tested this -> problem is that this would only resize the window length and width and not the contents like widgets (even if I loop over all widgets, the `adjustSize()` does not appear to do anything on widgets)

Comment: Mmh, are you completely sure you're correctly using a layout? Because if that happens, it means that you are probably *not* setting one, at least for the central widget (if you're using a QMainWindow) or the top level one. If you manually resize the window, does the content adjust itself? If not, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: @musicamante Yeah seems like odd behavior; however, the central widget actually does have a layout.. As I'm using Qt Creator, this would have appeared as a red mark.

Comment: I think you just need to call `widget->layout()->invalidate()` on all visible window widgets